# proc ID 1 is no longer "/sbin/init"?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade

I did an "apt-get dist-upgrade" on a 16.04.2 LTS system. I did not see any kernel related packages, so I did not reboot.

To my surprise, I no longer have `/sbin/init` (as shown by `ps -auxw` as root) as process ID 1; instead PID 1 is `/lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 20`.

Is this expected?
...or is this a side-effect of upgrading?
...and if I reboot, would I see `/sbin/init` return?

Comment: Yes it is expected because since version 15.04 Ubuntu has been transitioning to using systemd as it's init system